# Java HashMap Sepator and Fields

Tags: java, hashmap

I want use Separtor and different fields in hashmap, I am trying to write program to find duplicate firstname and lastname fields in data than add sequction number, 
Check firstname && lastname in all records 
if firstname && lastname found duplicate add seqNumber in feilds like 0,1,2,3..
if didn't find duplicate than 0

I write the code is working fine.. but, it checking line.. instead of fields, I need to check 2 fields firstname and lastname..

Please help me!!

here is inputdata file:- I have data file like:

```
CustmerNumber,FirstName,LastName,Address1,city
123456789,abcd,efgh,12 spring st,atlanta
2345678,xyz,lastname,16 sprint st,atlanta
232345678,abcd,efgh ,1201 sprint st,atlanta 
1234678,xyz,lastname,1234 oakbrook pkwy,atlanta
23556,abcd,efgh,3201 sprint st,atlanta
34564,robert,parker,12032 oakbrrok,atlanta
```

I want output data file like:

```
CustmerNumber,FirstName,LastName,Address1,city,**SEQNUMBER**
123456789,**abcd,efgh**,12 spring st,atlanta,**0**
232345678,**abcd,efgh** ,1201 sprint st,atlanta,**1** 
23556,**abcd,efgh**,3201 sprint st,atlanta,**2**
2345678,**xyz,lastname**,16 sprint st,atlanta,**0**
1234678,**xyz,lastname**,1234 oakbrook pkwy,atlanta,**1**
34564,**robert,parker**,12032 oakbrrok,atlanta,**0**
```

Here is my Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<>();

        File dir = new File("Data_File_In");

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

            s.nextLine();   

            while(s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                if(!names.containsKey(line)) {
                    names.put(line, 0);
                }
                names.put(line, names.get(line) + 1);
            }
            for(String name : names.keySet()) {
                for(int i = 1; i <= names.get(name); i++) {
                    System.out.println(name + "---->" + (i-1));
                }
            }

            s.close();

        }

    }

}
```

My Code is checking line if line is duplicate than sequction number is 0,1,2....
if not same like again than only 0 
Instead of that need to use fields firstname and lastname.. 
Please help me!!
Thanks!!

Comment: Use either String#split() to access individual fields or use [CSVReader](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html) and `CSVWriter` to read & write CSV files.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I really have no idea how to use fields in hashmap to find duplicates and add number 0,1,2,3..Please help me!! Thanks in Advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

Parse your line so you know the values of `firstName` and `lastName`
for each line. Then for each line use e.g. `firstName + "###" + lastName`
as the key of your map. The values in your map will be e.g. `Integer` values
(these are the counts). When reading a line, construct its key and see if it
is in the map already. If yes - increase the value i.e. the `count`, otherwise
add new entry in the map with `count=1`.

Comment: I don't know, how to use firstname and lastname fields in hashmap, can you please help me!! I m beginners in java please help me!! Thank in advanced!!

Comment: Can you please help me, Please..I don't know how to use fields and seperator in hashmap.. please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: Read line by line, call String.split. In the returned array you will have the firstName and the lastName.

Comment: so in that while loop i need to put                                     String[] actionID = line.split("\\,");

                     String PFN = actionID[1].trim();
                     String PLN = actionID[2].trim();                   than how i can use that in hashmap?? please help me!! Thanks!!